# SOLR Max requests queued per destination 3000 exceeded for HttpDestination + TIMED_WAITING

Tags: java, multithreading, solr

We are having SOLR (8.3.1) CLOUD (NRT) with Zookeeper Ensemble , 3 nodes
each on Centos VMs

SOLR Nodes has 66GB RAM, 15GB HEAP MEM, 4 CPUs.
Record Count: 3.3Million. Avg Doc Size is 350Kb.

Everything works fine until some disturbance happens with the cluser, due to load or network latancy issues. The threads in TIMED_WAITING increase to 7000+ and it stays until SOLR restart

Server 1:
*7722*  Threads are in TIMED_WATING
("lock":"java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@151d5f2f
")

Server 2:
*4046*   Threads are in TIMED_WATING
("lock":"java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@1e0205c3
")

Server 3:
*4210*   Threads are in TIMED_WATING
("lock":"java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@5ee792c0
")

How to increase the 3000 to something bigger?  will net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1 helps? what is the drawback? Please help.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

One of possible workaround is switch to http1 (solr option `-Dsolr.http1`)

Comment: This worked for us too!  More info here: https://lists.apache.org/thread/m0z7jnpll6fv110pw8mm8p9qx1dfodwn

Answer (score 0):

Validate System time/NTP Sync during error window. It might be one of the root cause. Also, watch for the explicit client's commits.

Comment: I haven't been able to spot any sync errors in the logs. Any ideas how to detect these?